# How to cancel automatic withdrawal on Trustwallet?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, trustwallet

My Trustwallet was compromised and I have some tokens staked on it. When I deposit eth or any other token, it’s automatically sent to a different address almost immediately. Kindly advise on the best thing to do.

Comment: MyCrypto wallet provides a service for recovering wallets that were compromised https://blog.mycrypto.com/how-to-beat-an-ethereum-based-sweeper-and-recover-your-assets/